# Рекурсивное заполнение TreeView

Tags: c#, рекурсия, winforms

Привет! Есть задача заполнить дерево TreeView из текстового файла древовидной структуры (вложенность определяется кол-вом табов в начале каждой строки). Написал класс:

```
public class Tree
{
    private List<TreeBranch> Child { get; set; }

    private void Fill(StreamReader stream)
    {
        bool isEmpty = true;

        Child = new List<TreeBranch>();

        TreeBranch treeBranch = new TreeBranch();

        treeBranch.Child = new List<dynamic>();

        while (!stream.EndOfStream)
        {
            string node = stream.ReadLine();

            int countTabs = GetCountTabs(node);

            if (!isEmpty && countTabs == 0)
            {
                Child.Add(treeBranch);

                treeBranch = new TreeBranch();

                treeBranch.Child = new List<dynamic>();

                treeBranch.Root = node;

                continue;
            }
            else if (isEmpty && countTabs == 0)
            {
                treeBranch.Root = node;
            }
            else
            {
                treeBranch.Child.Add(new { Name = node, Level = countTabs });
            }
            isEmpty = false;
        }
        Child.Add(treeBranch);
    }

    private int GetCountTabs(string node)
    {
        return node.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Count() - 1;
    }

    public void SetTreeView(StreamReader stream, TreeView treeView)
    {
        Fill(stream);

        foreach (var branch in Child)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(branch.Root);

            AddChildren(treeNode, branch.Child);

            treeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        }
    }

    private void AddChildren(TreeNode treeNode, List<dynamic> child)
    {
        foreach (var item in child)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(item.Name);
//здесь нужно применить рекурсию, в этом моя проблема
            AddChildren(newNode, (from node in child where item.Level - node.Level == 1 select node).ToList());

        }
    }
}
```

Метод Fill(StreamReader stream) генерирует List<TreeBranch>, у каждого объекта которого есть корневой родитель Root и список всех остальных потомков, у каждого потомка есть Name и Level(степень вложенности).
Класс TreeBranch:

```
    public class TreeBranch
{
    public string Root { get; set; }
    public List<dynamic> Child { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и собственно на форме есть кнопка и дерево. Обработчик события кнопки:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader fileSteram= new StreamReader("tree1.txt");
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        tree.SetTreeView(fileSteram, treeView1);           
    }
```

В методе SetTreeView(StreamReader stream, TreeView treeView) нужно чтобы вызывался рекурсивный метод AddChildren. В нем проблема.. Помогите решить, пожалуйста, кому не трудно.. не могу применить рекурсию.. срочно надо.. Спасибо!

Пример текстового файла из 2 объектов типа TreeBranch:

```
1living things
plants
animals
    inverterbrates
    verterbrates
        birds
            flying birds
            land birds
            water birds
        fish
        amphibians
        reptiles
        mammals
2living things
plants
animals
    inverterbrates
    verterbrates
        birds
            flying birds
            land birds
            water birds
        fish
        amphibians
        reptiles
        mammals
```

[Обновлено]

```
private void AddChildren(TreeNode treeNode, List<dynamic> child)
    {
        var newchild = (from node in child where node.Parent == treeNode.Text select node).ToList();
        foreach (var item in newchild)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(item.Name);
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
            AddChildren(newNode, child);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? Не компилируется? Выбрасывает исключение? Ведёт себя не так, как надо?

Comment: нужно правильно определить рекурсивный метод AddChildren, у меня это не выходит..

Comment: AddChildren(treeNode, (from node in child where item.Level - node.Level == 1 select node).ToList());
эта строка явно неверная..

Comment: немного подправил код, добавил isEmpty=false, а то не работал для нескольких объектов..

Comment: А что не так в текущей реализации? Что не так с ` (from node in child where item.Level - node.Level == 1 select node).ToList()`?

Comment: во всем разобрался, позже скину сюда рабочий вариант.. может кому-нибудь понадобиться:)

Comment: Если можно поделитесь кодом

Answer (score 2):

Долго смотрел в код пока не понял, что мне именно не нравиться :). А именно если переделать класс TreeBranch

```
   public class TreeBranch
   {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public List<TreeBranch> Child { get; set; }
   }
```

То ломать голову над тем как сделать рекурсию совсем не придется.