# Заполнение TreeView

Tags: c#, рекурсия, .net, winforms

Всем привет!
Не могу придумать алгоритм, как заполнить TreeView, зная только степень вложенности элемента.
Например:

```
root1(степень вложенности 0)
  dir1(степень вложенности 1)
    file1(степень вложенности 2)
    file2(степень вложенности 2)
  dir2(степень вложенности 1)
root2(степень вложенности 0)  
....
```

Степень вложенности - это, грубо говоря, количество пробелов (табуляций) от начала строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри [Рекурсивное заполнение TreeView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/208837/c-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-treeview)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но на строчке 
var newchild = (from node in child where node.Parent == treeNode.Text select node).ToList(), а конкретно в node.Parent == treeNode.Text
вылетает исключение <>f__AnonymousType0<string,int>. Не могу найти в чем проблема, Вы с таким не сталкивались?

Comment: нет, проблем не возникало.. вот https://cloud.mail.ru/public/d94f31f511cb/Tree.rar посмотри 2 проекта, там есть 2 реализации заполнения дерева

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень выручили.